# Parametric polymorphism breaks when an implicit is expected in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit, parametric-polymorphism

I get

> No Json serializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

in

```
import play.api.libs.json._

trait A[T] {
  def foo(t: T) = bar(Json.toJson(t))
}
```

I will have a `Writes` for the *actual* parameter type but I don't see that that would clear up the compilation error. After some googling, I feel like there may be something fundamental missing in my understanding on the subject. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be `Json.toJson` Am i right ?

Comment: @pamu yes, thanks! modded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message isn't very clear in this case—you don't need to implement a `Writes` for this type, you just need to prove to the compiler that you have one:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

trait A[T] {
  def foo(t: T)(implicit w: Writes[T]) = bar(Json.toJson(t))
}
```

This will work as expected. You could also have an `implicit def w: Writes[T]`  in the trait, which would require instantiators to provide an instance, which is more restrictive in that you can't instantiate an `A` without an instance, but it's syntactically a little cleaner if you have a lot of methods like this, and you may actually want the restriction to kick in earlier, rather than after you've already got an `A` instantiated and you're trying to call `foo` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Provide `implicit def writes`

```
import play.api.libs.json._

trait A[T] {
  implicit def writes: Writes[T]
  def foo(t: T) = bar(Json.toJson(t))
}
```

or provide writes as `implicit` parameter to `foo`

```
import play.api.libs.json._

trait A[T] {
  def foo(t: T)(implicit writes: Writes[T]): JsValue = bar(Json.toJson(t))
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong—in your second example the `T` in the method will shadow the one on the trait, which is never what you want and can lead to extremely confusing issues.

Comment: @TravisBrown edited the answer . thanks for suggesting

Comment: But that completely changes the semantics of the OP's `A`. :)

Comment: @TravisBrown looks like `implicit` param is the way to go.. edited the answer . thanks for suggestion